# Do some effect when removing a object

Tags: knockout.js

When I use '.pop' or '.remove', knockout automatically removes the elements corresponding in html dom.
My question is: Can I do some effect like '.hide' of jquery when removing this objects from array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the beforeRemove callback of the foreach binding:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

The animated transition may help demonstrate how to do the animation:

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html